# Turn an array into a hash with keys matching values

Tags: ruby

If I have the following array:

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Is there a simple way in Ruby to make it into a hash that looks like:

```
{ 'a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c', 'd' => 'd', 'e' => 'e' }
```

I can do this:

```
Hash[foo.map{|a| [a, a]}]
```

which works just fine, but I'm curious if there's some other way.

Comment: There are other ways too, but that way is perfectly acceptable and it's concise and would be used most often.

Answer (score 5):

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

[foo, foo].transpose.to_h
#=> {"a"=>"a", "b"=>"b", "c"=>"c", "d"=>"d", "e"=>"e"}

foo.zip(foo).to_h
#=> {"a"=>"a", "b"=>"b", "c"=>"c", "d"=>"d", "e"=>"e"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you need a hash with *just* those values, or would a hash with a self-default be fine?

For example:

```
Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = k }
```

You can also do this and combine it with itself into pairs:

```
Hash[foo.zip(foo)]
```

Comment: Oooh! I like zip()!  That's the kind of Ruby magic I was wondering about. :-)

Comment: @Dan, it won't be long before you see `zip` as pretty pedestrian.

Comment: Once you have `h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = k } => {}` you can write `h.values_at(*foo) #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]` which results in `h
 #=> {"a"=>"a", "b"=>"b", "c"=>"c", "d"=>"d", "e"=>"e"}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way of doing it:

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
foo.inject({}){ |h,k| h[k] = k; h }
```

As suggested on comments, a better variations of this answer uses the `each_with_object`, so it gets rid off the trailing `; h`:

```
foo.each_with_object({}) { |e,h| h[e]=e }
```

The advantage of either is that no intermediate array is constructed.

But the way you mentioned will work just fine:

```
Hash[foo.map{|a| [a, a]}]
```

Comment: I suggest you get rid of the pesky `;h` by writing `foo.each_with_object({}) { |e,h| h[e]=e }`. Either way, it has the advantage that, unlike `zip` then `Hash[]` or `to_h`, no intermediate array is constructed.

Comment: Agreed. `each_with_object` is preferable to `inject` in this case, actually in a lot of cases, because it doesn't require the trailing `;h`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue does not make sense. I suspect it is an XY-problem. If you actually don't need to store the key-values in the hash, but just need to return the key back, then:

```
h = Hash.new{|_, k| k}
h["a"] # => "a"
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland You were faster. Please undelete your answer.

Comment: It was too close to evedovelli's, so I left a comment instead.

Comment: It's a weird use-case. I define a bunch of languages and I'm building a default translation table. So if I have languages as: ['en', 'fr', 'de', 'ru'] I want to easily build out the initial translation hash: { 'en' => 'en', 'fr' => 'fr', 'de' => 'de', 'ru' => 'ru' }. That's why I was asking. (note, the algorithm then goes through some other data and adjusts the translation table, but the X => X default makes it easier, in my specific use case)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
foo  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
hash = Hash[foo.zip foo]
```